# Using the Plaid API on Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, plaid

I am trying to make an android application that uses the Plaid API. I am using the java bindings found here: https://github.com/plaid/plaid-java.

I am trying run the example code found on that github page, but I'm struggling. The problem lies in the dependencies.

I have these in my build.gradle:

```
    compile 'com.plaid:plaid-java:0.2.12'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
```

It took a good amount of searching to find the correct Apache HttpClient library that would work, because I was getting ClassNotFoundExcptions when I first tried this.

Now I'm getting a VerifyError:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.plaid.client.http.ApacheHttpClientHttpDelegate due to bad method com.plaid.client.http.HttpResponseWrapper com.plaid.client.http.ApacheHttpClientHttpDelegate.doPatch(com.plaid.client.http.PlaidHttpRequest, java.lang.Class) (declaration of 'com.plaid.client.http.ApacheHttpClientHttpDelegate' appears in
```

I am struggling to resolve these problems and can't find any examples of the Plaid API working on Android. If anyone can provide even the slightest bit of help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: As you've discovered, just because an API has Java support, doesn't necessarily mean Android can support it. That being said, one way around that is to directly connect to the REST API they seem to have

Comment: You may want to look at the very last part of this page. http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html

Comment: @cricket_007 unfortunately adding that state doesn't seem to work. I'd like the access the REST API, but I have a question. The Plaid documentation uses curl to make the Https request, but I'm a bit lost on how to bring that into android. An example can be found here in the sample request: https://plaid.com/docs/api/#gaining-access I can make the request in the terminal, but I don't know how to bring that to android.

Comment: You can use any HTTP library to make a POST request..      https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-form-parameters

Comment: what was your verdict on this @GarrettFitzgerald?